# Permanent url redirection using htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

I want to redirect an url from the form :

- /cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi/

to the form :

- http://www.domain.com/

I tried this but did not work

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi/ http://www.domain.com/
```

Is there a way to redirect it?

Comment: Your code looks like it should work. what actually is your problem?

Comment: theres no problem actually.. a client just wants this link /cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi/ be directed to the homepage link. anyway thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it doesn't like the trailing '/'.  Try this:

```
Redirect 301 /cgi-sys/suspendedpage.cgi http://www.domain.com/
```